# What is the function to get plugin base url in multisite?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite, functions

I'm using this function `plugins_url()`.

But it always echoes main site url even in subsite.

So i'm getting ajax errors like `Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Lets say my main domain name is `blahblah.com` and my subdomain is `mysubdomain.blahblah.com`

Is there any function available that returns `mysubdomain.blahblah.com/wp-content/plugins` instead of `blahblah.com/wp-content/plugins`?

Thanks

### Update:

As of now i'm using like this.

```
home_url( '/' ).'wp-content/plugins/'.str_replace(basename(__FILE__),"",plugin_basename(__FILE__))
```

Here `wp-content/plugins/` text hard coded.

So any other alternative method there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) function is designed to work in WordPress Multisite. Here is an example of its proper usage:

> ```
> <?php
> echo "<img src="' .plugins_url( 'images/wordpress.png' , __FILE__ ). '" > ';
> ?>
> ```
>
> If you are using this function in a file that is nested inside a
>   subdirectory, you should use PHP's dirname() function:
>
> ```
> <?php
> echo "<img src="' .plugins_url( 'images/wordpress.png' , dirname(__FILE__) ). '" > ';
> ?>
> ```